# КАК исправить ifМodule в htaccess для перенаправления на страницу 404?

Tags: php

```
    # redirect all requests to index.php loader
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</IfModule>
```